# "blind" Keras CNN , 100 % accuracy, no prediction power

Tags: keras

I am new to Keras and trying to build an image detection based on a dataset of images of all images (150 x 150) with and without marks.
My code is based on the Deep Learning book by Francois Chollet.
Jupyter NB, Keras  2.2.0, tensorflow

I make two classes ("clean wall" and "marked wall"), to be able to show the activation (softmax instead of sigmoid), as described in the book showing the last conv layer activation, and to use more classes later.

My problem is (with ~30000 clean images and ~40 marked), all 150x150, the model runs at once into 100% accuracy with no loss - but without identifying any marked image as marked if I predict one later. (the same model worked perfectly on 100 cat images, manually having marked same pictures with an additional mini-image as the second class, and resizing all from bigger pics to 150x150).

total training images (1 and 0): 28980 and 47
total validation images (1 and 0): 28980 and 6

Prediction is always "clean" with a high percentage, even on all original marked images, changed marked images (via generator), anything.

Any suggestions, please? Am I making a false assumption/did I miss something somewhere?

Thnx in advance!

by Andy

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                    input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
          metrics=['acc'])

# Preprocess images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  rescale=1./255,
  rotation_range=20, 
  width_shift_range=0.2, 
  height_shift_range=0.2, 
  shear_range=0.2, 
  zoom_range=0.2, 
  vertical_flip=True,
  horizontal_flip=True,
  fill_mode='reflect')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    # This is the target directory
    train_dir,
    # All images will be resized to 150x150
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=16,
    # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical')

# train the model

for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
  print('data batch shape:', data_batch.shape)
  print('labels batch shape:', labels_batch.shape)
  break

history = model.fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch=10,
  epochs=5,
  validation_data=validation_generator,
  validation_steps=10)
```

Output:

```
data batch shape: (16, 150, 150, 3)
labels batch shape: (16, 2)
Epoch 1/5
5/5 [==============================] - 17s 3s/step - loss: 0.5646 - acc: 0.8625 - val_loss: 0.3196 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/5
5/5 [==============================] - 18s 4s/step - loss: 0.2201 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0823 - val_acc: 1.0000 ...
```

Comment: I uploaded an example image as my profile pic.

Comment: the pics are all 96dpi if that matters, bit depth 24, created with scipy.misc.imsave(pathI, img), after loaded, eventually split up, preprocessed with: x = image.img_to_array(img); x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape); The cats had 1 dpi, sRGB, resolution 2, 2 compressed bits per pixel.... does that matter in the model?

Answer (score 1):

seems, it starts to see. *g*

Main change: same number of negative pictures, more similar to positive ones.

One more dense layer for complexity.

Thnx to anyone having dropped a thought on the solution *g*

BR Andy